# Can I show a custom mouse cursor while dragging a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, css, html, drag-and-drop

By 'custom' I mean something other than the standard copy/move/link cursors defined by `event.dataTransfer.dropEffect`; for example, the `grabbing` or `-webkit-grabbing` cursor. It appears that `dropEffect` overrides any CSS I set on the dragged element?

Here's what I have tried so far: http://jsfiddle.net/QhKbB/1/

Comment: Best thing would be to disable default drag behavior of different browsers and implement that yourself with overlaying absolute div (with image background).

Comment: If that turns out to be the only option, then I'll do that. It's a pity though: drag-and-drop is among the few HTML5 features natively supported by all the browsers out there.